# Error messages at shutdown of Dell laptop with Mint 21.3 and kernel 5.15.0-101

Tags: linux-mint, logs, shutdown

For about a week or two I see some error messages at the shutdown of my Dell Inspiron 7577 laptop with Linux Mint 21.3 and kernel 5.15.0-101-generic. I have no idea where or if they are logged somewhere, so I made a photo, the best one is this, click to enlarge, it is quite okay and readable (If there is any log I could copy-paste it from, please comment. I hope my computer is not defective or something...):

[image: Error messages at shutdown of Dell laptop with Mint 21.3 and kernel 5.15.0-101]

Comment: Possibly unrelated but the *"Tainted **shutdown**"* looks surprising to me. Did you install some out of tree (proprietary) driver or something recently ?

Comment: And also what is this unmountable *"/oldroot"* device

Comment: @MC68020 Hello. I almost forgot but I did update nvidia-driver-535 to 545 version. I just have no idea if it can be related.

Comment: @MC68020 oldroot does not exist, I have no idea what that is about. I just reverted back to nvidia 535 driver version, same stuff at shutdown. I am clueless. :((

Comment: It must exist somewhere. Maybe as a residual line in some config file? But since it is attempting to unmount it, and we don't get "not found" errors but "device busy" that would suggest the thing actually does exist somewhere. Anything in your fstab? Not that that could explain it... Maybe some old systemd hook?

Comment: @terdon I used my search for hours, and got some pointers _that it could be_ a bug in systemd.

Comment: @terdon But that was days ago, I originally have thought I would solve it, but it appears I will not be able to. So I did not make any notes, or lists of potential bug candidates.